# How to show listview item content based on id?

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView activity class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] naziviMolitvi = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nazivi_molitvi);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, naziviMolitvi));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Molitva.class);
                //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //bundle.putInt("pozicija", position);
                //intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                      ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I have list items stored in strings.xml file in string-array:

```
<string-array name="nazivi_molitvi">
    <item>Дневне молитве</item>
    <item>Символ вере</item>
    <item>Псалм 50</item>
    <item>Свакодневна молитва</item>
    <item>Молитва Пресветој Богородици у невољи и потиштености</item>
    <item>Поздрав Богородици</item>
    <item>Јутарња молитва</item>
    <item>Вечерња молитва</item>
    <item>Молитва Анђелу Чувару</item>
    <item>Молитва пред Свето Причешће</item>
    <item>Молитва после Светог Причешћа</item>
    <item>Молитва за међусобни мир</item>
    <item>Молитва пре учења</item>
    <item>Молитва после учења</item>
    <item>Молитва пре доручка</item>
    <item>Молитва после доручка</item>
    <item>Молитва пре ручка</item>
    <item>Молитва после ручка</item>
    <item>Молитва пре вечере</item>
    <item>Молитва после вечере</item>
    <item>Десет Божијих Заповести</item>
    <item>Две највеће Христове Заповести</item>
    <item>Химна Светом Сави</item>
    <item>Српска Химна "Боже правде"</item>
</string-array>
```

Now when user clicks on single item I want to show expanded text for that view. Where to store this text? If I store text in string array then I don't know how to reference to single item in it.
Maybe for every item to make string with certain name and when user clicks item in list view to have switch statement, like this:

```
public class Molitva extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.molitva);
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        int pozicija = bundle.getInt("pozicija");
        TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        tv.append(" - " + getPrayerText(pozicija));

    }
}
```

Is that good practice for selecting list item and what you suggest me? How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the list of expanded text is the same size as your list, and the indices are equal and corresponding.

You can also store the expanded text list on arrays.xml and get hold of them as you did with your non-expanded list - using `getResources().getStringArray`. You can use the position you passed in the bundle to get the item in your expanded text list.

```
String[] expanded_text = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.expanded_text);
```

// to get the item at position `pozicija`

```
expanded_text[pozicija];
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'd use for it, if had such stuff

JSON object in assets or raw file

```
[
    {
        name="Дневне молитве",
        content="some content"
    },
    {
        name="Символ вере",
        content="some other content"
    }
]
```

Java object

```
class Molitva {
 public String name;
 public String content;
}
```

and using google gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library it will be transphormed to array of Molitva easily

```
Molitva[] molitvas = new Gson().fromJson(stringWithJsonArrays, Molitva[].class);
```

The next step gonna be implement Parcelable in Molitva class and send it with intent to the next activity. Or you can send it by parts.

Solution is for question only. If you gonna have over 9000 Molitvas in your application, use database(sqlite).

Comment: Good answer but it's simpler to do like Josephus Villarey said, because his solution doesn't require external library. I will have max 30, maybe 40 prays.

Comment: sure it is :) I just love abstraction, and fear mess in ids :)